# How to calculate centrality of graph nodes in neo4j and cypher

Tags: javascript, node.js, neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to calculate the eigenvector/page rank centrality for a neo4j graph. I've found that we could do it with gremlin plugin. I have already written the code in cql. Is it possible to use both gremlin and cypher. If not then how to calculate centrality using cypher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be tough with Cypher alone. You may want to take a look at [APOC Procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_centrality_algorithms), which includes procedures for closeness and betweenness centrality.

Comment: Thank you.I will look into it. Would there'd be function to calculate page rank or eigen centrality?